# Application hangs when using two debugger at the same time

Tags: c#, ignite

I have two same console applications running at same time.
The following is the execrpt of C# code

```
IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(config);

ICache<int, string> cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, string>("CC");
```

If I put a breakpoints at GetOrCreateCache line and start dubuggering mode for two applications, the first running application will hit the breakpoint, but not the second one. The second one will just hang there.

I checked the log. It kept repeating the following content

```
Next node remains the same [nextId=d0bb3ac1-03ae-4833-b739-465c4e3db0d1, nextOrder=1]
Message has been sent to next node [msg=TcpDiscoveryHeartbeatMessage [super=TcpDiscoveryAbstractMessage [sndNodeId=26a833d1-7ca1-4482-9bf4-99fa837681ce, id=333395e7b51-d0bb3ac1-03ae-4833-b739-465c4e3db0d1, verifierNodeId=d0bb3ac1-03ae-4833-b739-465c4e3db0d1, topVer=0, pendingIdx=0, failedNodes=null, isClient=false]], next=d0bb3ac1-03ae-4833-b739-465c4e3db0d1, res=1]
Message has been received: TcpDiscoveryHeartbeatMessage [super=TcpDiscoveryAbstractMessage [sndNodeId=26a833d1-7ca1-4482-9bf4-99fa837681ce, id=333395e7b51-d0bb3ac1-03ae-4833-b739-465c4e3db0d1, verifierNodeId=d0bb3ac1-03ae-4833-b739-465c4e3db0d1, topVer=0, pendingIdx=0, failedNodes=null, isClient=false]]
Processing message [cls=TcpDiscoveryHeartbeatMessage, id=333395e7b51-d0bb3ac1-03ae-4833-b739-465c4e3db0d1]
Message has been added to queue: TcpDiscoveryHeartbeatMessage [super=TcpDiscoveryAbstractMessage [sndNodeId=26a833d1-7ca1-4482-9bf4-99fa837681ce, id=333395e7b51-d0bb3ac1-03ae-4833-b739-465c4e3db0d1, verifierNodeId=d0bb3ac1-03ae-4833-b739-465c4e3db0d1, topVer=0, pendingIdx=0, failedNodes=null, isClient=false]]
Discovery notification [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4cd6f0f5-2f75-4375-97fa-b7f6e4e2c0cd, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 172.30.29.142], sockAddrs=[EDISONCWRK2.meridianlink.com/172.30.29.142:47501, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47501, /127.0.0.1:47501], discPort=47501, order=4, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1492473879345, loc=true, ver=1.9.0#20170302-sha1:0be92732, isClient=false], spiState=CONNECTED, type=NODE_METRICS_UPDATED, topVer=4]
```

Does anyone know the reason or how to fix the problem?
I ask this question because I am working on a project in a team.
If multiple team members debug at the same time, it may cause problem.

Environment: Ignite.NET 1.9, Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two applications join the same Ignite cluster. When one node stops at a breakpoint, all threads are suspended. This node no longer responds to network communications. This is what causes the other node to hang - it waits for the response.

You have to avoid suspending one app and debugging the other at the same time.

As for team work, each team member should work in their own isolated environment to avoid interferring with others. This can be achieved by setting up firewall rules or by tweaking `IgniteConfiguration` like this:

```
        var c = new IgniteConfiguration
        {
            Localhost = "127.0.0.1",
            DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
            {
                IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder
                {
                    Endpoints = new[] {"127.0.0.1:47500"}
                },
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!